# Bootstrap Modal with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I'm trying to open a modal for my create account section. I put that html part in an .erb file, but I can't link it and can't find information anywhere. This is my first time with Sinatra. I've tried with "link_to", but there's no link_to in Sinatra. What can I do?

This is my login.erb code:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Examen Parcial</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/login.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
  <div class="login-page">
   <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <input id="user" type="text" placeholder="Usuario"/>
      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Contrase&#241a"/>

        <a>
          <button id="boton_ingreso" type="button">Ingresar</button>
        </a>
        <div id="adver" class="error1"></div>

      <p class="message" style="display:inline-block">¿No está registrado?</p> <%= link_to "Crear cuenta", "#my-modal", :class => "btn", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my modal.erb code:

```
</div>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="header">Crear cuenta</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="titulo">Condiciones de uso</div>
                <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
                  in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check">  <span class="acepto">Acepto los Términos y Condiciones</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form data-toggle="validator" name="myForm" method="post">
                <button id="boton" type="button" disabled="true" class="btn btn-success">Guardar Cambios</button>
             </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" role="dialog">
```

And this is my routes.rb code:

require 'sinatra'

```
get '/login' do
  erb :login
end

get '/login/createaccount' do
  erb :modal
end
```

Please help me!

Comment: That's not how bootstrap modals work.  Move the modal into the login HTML, initially hidden.  Then use data-toggle or javascript to show it.

Comment: Apart from the wrong use of modals you want to use partials. It's in the sinatra readme.